# Center Align ListItemContent and Center the List in a DIV

Tags: css, reactjs, list, material-ui, listitem

I am trying and failing miserably to center this List underneath "Contact Me" and the hr tag. Those to things are centered perfectly in the column but the list and icons are left justified and Ideally I would like them in the center like everything else. I have tried justify content, and text align but I am probably putting them in the wrong place.

Assume I have no CSS and walk me through it haha.

Thank you so much.

```
<Cell col={6}>
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div className="contact-list-con">
       <List>
         <ListItem>
           <ListItemContent style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax', fontFamily: 'Julius Sans One'}}>
             <Icon style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax'}}>perm_phone_msg</Icon>
             <a href="tel:">888-888-8888</a>
           </ListItemContent>
         </ListItem>

         <ListItem>
           <ListItemContent style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax', fontFamily: 'Julius Sans One'}}>
             <Icon style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax'}}>email</Icon>
             <a href="mailto:">hello@helloworld.com</a>
           </ListItemContent>
         </ListItem>
       </List>
     </div>
 </Cell>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, either with the code snippet feature or CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="centered">
<Cell col={6}>
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div class="contact-list-con">
       <List>
         <ListItem>
           <ListItemContent style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax', fontFamily: 'Julius Sans One'}}>
             <Icon style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax'}}>perm_phone_msg</Icon>
             <a href="tel:">888-888-8888</a>
           </ListItemContent>
         </ListItem>

         <ListItem>
           <ListItemContent style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax', fontFamily: 'Julius Sans One'}}>
             <Icon style={{fontSize:'2.13vmax'}}>email</Icon>
             <a href="mailto:">hello@helloworld.com</a>
           </ListItemContent>
         </ListItem>
       </List>
     </div>
 </Cell>
</div>
```

```
.centered{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:center;
width:100%;
}
.contact-list-con{
width:auto;
}
```

If you put it in a flex container you can center it without having to use `left, right, position`

Comment: I took your answer but just applied the css you provided for the .centered div to the contact-list-con div AND IT WORKED! I have been working on this pesky issue FOR AGES. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. If you had a problem with ```justify-content``` initially you have to make sure the element you are applying it to has ```display:flex```  and also a ```width``` is specified to the flex container, else the container will auto size and there will be no area for the child to be centered in.